Python simple graphic showing a small line to much
simple question i guess, why is it showing a small corner on the right side? And how to fix it?

from graphics import Canvas

CANVAS_WIDTH = 400
CANVAS_HEIGHT = 200
N_BOXES = 5
BOX_SIZE = CANVAS_WIDTH // N_BOXES

def main():
    canvas = Canvas(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT)
    for i in range (5):
        left_x =  i * 80
        top_y = 120
        right_x = left_x + BOX_SIZE 
        bottom_y = top_y + BOX_SIZE 
        canvas.create_rectangle(left_x,top_y,right_x ,bottom_y ,"white", "black")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

to fill the bottom side with BOX_SIZE 5 times

Have you checked the documentation for the [non-standard] graphics module?
